# Normalised Root Mean square error

Tags: normalization, error, rms

I have $10$ people in a group and they undergone a surgery. I have the root mean square of each subject before and after the surgery.

```
 Before     After
215.8231  105.7031
 35.0819   12.1916
 79.9559   32.8467
 75.0798   44.2913
 44.6203   18.8178
 21.207    16.5595
 56.8157   39.198
205.3445  110.0515
 39.8429   16.0174
116.1561   46.5451
 15.6692    9.5832
```

I would like to make these values to range between $0$-$1$. I used the formula $(\mathrm{value}-\min)/(\max-\min)$ for each group but it's not correct because I am loosing the information if the RMSE dropped down after the surgery.

Should I assume that my whole population is the Before and After and find the min value and max value?

What I did I found the min and max value before and then after and I normalised accordingly. I ended up with the following:

```
  Before       After
1            0.95671869
0.09698887   0.02596242
0.32118635   0.23155065
0.29682459   0.3454632
0.1446442    0.09191556
0.35341945   0.06943782
0.20557431   0.2947676
0.94764729   1
0.12077556   0.06404209
0.50204817   0.36789614
0            0
```

This way I don't know if the RMSE has been reduced.

Should I use $\min=9.5832$ and $\max=215.8231$ to the formula $(\mathrm{value}-\min)/(\max-\min)$ since those are the smallest and biggest numbers before and after? Would that be correct? I think I am loosing all the magnitude info this way but not sure how to work it out.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to normalize the errors?

Comment: I thought that will be better to present the error in values between 0-1.